# Software hanging at B.N instruction in disassembler -- No idea what it means

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

I'm trying to debug some software I've written for the NXP LPC1850 evaluation board. At the moment, when I halt my code I cannot see where it at in my C code, but I can in the disassembler window.

The line it is hanging on is at address 0x40. The instruction is B.N . I've looked it up on the ARM Information Center but I don't know anything about assembler and I'm afraid that even after reading around it means nothing to me.

```
      0x0: 0x9ff0         LDR       R7, [SP, #0x3c0]
      0x2: 0x1008         ASRS      R0, R1, #32
      0x4: 0x2bad         CMP       R3, #173                ; 0xad
      0x6: 0x1040         ASRS      R0, R0, #1
      0x8: 0x0041         LSLS      R1, R0, #1
      0xa: 0x1040         ASRS      R0, R0, #1
      0xc: 0x0043         LSLS      R3, R0, #1
      0xe: 0x1040         ASRS      R0, R0, #1
     0x10: 0x0045         LSLS      R5, R0, #1
     0x12: 0x1040         ASRS      R0, R0, #1
     0x14: 0x0047         LSLS      R7, R0, #1
     0x16: 0x1040         ASRS      R0, R0, #1
     0x18: 0x0049         LSLS      R1, R1, #1
     0x1a: 0x1040         ASRS      R0, R0, #1
     0x1c: 0x0000         MOVS      R0, R0
     0x1e: 0x0000         MOVS      R0, R0
     0x20: 0x0000         MOVS      R0, R0
     0x22: 0x0000         MOVS      R0, R0
     0x24: 0x0000         MOVS      R0, R0
     0x26: 0x0000         MOVS      R0, R0
     0x28: 0x0000         MOVS      R0, R0
     0x2a: 0x0000         MOVS      R0, R0
     0x2c: 0x004b         LSLS      R3, R1, #1
     0x2e: 0x1040         ASRS      R0, R0, #1
     0x30: 0x004d         LSLS      R5, R1, #1
     0x32: 0x1040         ASRS      R0, R0, #1
     0x34: 0x0000         MOVS      R0, R0
     0x36: 0x0000         MOVS      R0, R0
     0x38: 0x004f         LSLS      R7, R1, #1
     0x3a: 0x1040         ASRS      R0, R0, #1
     0x3c: 0x1645         ASRS      R5, R0, #25
     0x3e: 0x1040         ASRS      R0, R0, #1
     0x40: 0xe7fe         B.N       0x40
     0x42: 0xe7fe         B.N       0x42
     0x44: 0xe7fe         B.N       0x44
     0x46: 0xe7fe         B.N       0x46
     0x48: 0xe7fe         B.N       0x48
     0x4a: 0xe7fe         B.N       0x4a
     0x4c: 0xe7fe         B.N       0x4c
     0x4e: 0xe7fe         B.N       0x4e
     0x50: 0x0000         MOVS      R0, R0
     0x52: 0x0000         MOVS      R0, R0
     0x54: 0x0000         MOVS      R0, R0
     0x56: 0x0000         MOVS      R0, R0
     0x58: 0x0000         MOVS      R0, R0
     0x5a: 0x0000         MOVS      R0, R0
     0x5c: 0x0000         MOVS      R0, R0
     0x5e: 0x0000         MOVS      R0, R0
```

I would be immensely grateful if somebody could explain what is going on and perhaps why program is hanging at that point.

*edit:* added C code in below

```
#include "NXP\iolpc4350.h"
#include "stdint.h"
#include "modules\i2c_drv.h"
#include "modules\drv_nvic.h"

#define IRC_FREQ       12000000
#define XTAL_FREQ      12000000

//nt32_t ClockFrequency;

uint32_t I2C0_PCLK;

unsigned char Data[2];

#define MULTF 15

#define PCA9502_ADDR  0x4D

volatile uint8_t flag0=0;

#define flTick               ( flag0 )
#define flTickSet()          ( flag0 = 0xFF )
#define flTickClear()        ( flag0 = 0x00 )

/*************************************************************************
 * Function Name: InitClock
 * Parameters: none
 *
 * Return: none
 *
 * Description: Initialize PLL and clock dividers. FCCO = 320MHz,
 *              PLL1_OUT = 160MHz
 *
 *************************************************************************/
void InitClock(void)
{
  /* 1. Init XTAL OSC */
  CGU_XTAL_OSC_CTRL_bit.HF = 0;       /* Xtal.freq is between 1MHz and 15MHZ */
  CGU_XTAL_OSC_CTRL_bit.BYPASS = 0;   /* Xtal.osc is connected */
  CGU_XTAL_OSC_CTRL_bit.ENABLE = 0;   /* Xtal.osc is enabled */

  /* 2.  Wait for OSC ready > 2ms */
  for(volatile uint32_t j = 20000; j; j--);

  /* 3. Switch to OSC clk */
  /* BASE_M4_CLK */
  CGU_BASE_M4_CLK = (1ul  << 11)      /* Autoblock during freq.change enabled */
                  | (6ul  << 24)      /* Source is XTAL osc. */
                    ;
  /* BASE_APB1_CLK */
  CGU_BASE_APB1_CLK = (1ul  << 11)    /* Autoblock during freq.change enabled */
                    | (6ul  << 24)    /* Source is XTAL osc. */
                    ;
  /* BASE_APB3_CLK */
  CGU_BASE_APB3_CLK = (1ul  << 11)    /* Autoblock during freq.change enabled */
                    | (6ul  << 24)    /* Source is XTAL osc. */
                    ;
  /* BASE_SPIFI_CLK */
  CGU_BASE_SPIFI_CLK = (1ul  << 11)   /* Autoblock during freq.change enabled */
                     | (6ul  << 24)   /* Source is XTAL osc. */
                    ;

  /* 4. Init PLL1 - In clk - OSC (12MHz)
     N = 3, M = 80, P = 1 VCO - 320MHz, PLL1 OUT - 160MHz */
  CGU_PLL1_CTRL_bit.PD = 1;           /* Power down PLL1 */
  CGU_PLL1_CTRL_bit.BYPASS = 0;       /* CCO clock sent to post-dividers */
  CGU_PLL1_CTRL_bit.DIRECT = 0;       /* Direct CCO output disabled */
  CGU_PLL1_CTRL_bit.FBSEL = 0;        /* CCO output as feedback divider */
  CGU_PLL1_CTRL_bit.PSEL = 1-1;       /* Post divider P = 1 */
  CGU_PLL1_CTRL_bit.NSEL = 3-1;       /* N = 3 */
  CGU_PLL1_CTRL_bit.MSEL = 80-1;      /* M = 80 */
  CGU_PLL1_CTRL_bit.CLK_SEL = 6;      /* Source is XTAL osc. */
  CGU_PLL1_CTRL_bit.AUTOBLOCK = 1;    /* Autoblock during freq.change enabled */

  /* 5. Enable PLL1 */
  CGU_PLL1_CTRL_bit.PD = 0;           /* Power up (enable) PLL1 */

  /* 5. Wait for the PLL1 to achieve lock */
  while(!CGU_PLL1_STAT_bit.LOCK);

  /* 6. Dividers */
  /* IDIVA - /4 input 160MHz, output 40MHz */
  CGU_IDIVA_CTRL_bit.AUTOBLOCK = 1;   /* Autoblock during freq.change enabled */
  CGU_IDIVA_CTRL_bit.IDIV = 4-1;      /* IDIV = 4 */
  CGU_IDIVA_CTRL_bit.CLK_SEL = 9;     /* Source is PLL1 */
  CGU_IDIVA_CTRL_bit.PD = 0;          /* Enable IDIVA */

  /* 7. Init Clock output stages */
  /* BASE_M4_CLK, APB0, APB2 - 160MHz */
  CGU_BASE_M4_CLK = (1ul  << 11)      /* Autoblock during freq.change enabled */
                  | (9ul  << 24)      /* Source is PLL1 */
                    ;
  /* BASE_APB1_CLK - 160MHz*/
  CGU_BASE_APB1_CLK = (1ul  << 11)    /* Autoblock during freq.change enabled */
                    | (9ul << 24)     /* Source is PLL1 */
                    ;
  /* BASE_SPIFI_CLK - 40MHz */
  CGU_BASE_SPIFI_CLK = (1ul  << 11)   /* Autoblock during freq.change enabled */
                     | (12ul << 24)   /* Source is IDIVA */
                    ;
  /* Enable M4 Bus clock */
  CCU1_CLK_M4_BUS_CFG_bit.RUN = 1;

  /* Enable APB 1 Bus clock */
  CCU1_CLK_APB1_BUS_CFG_bit.RUN = 1;

  /* Enable SCU clock */
  CCU1_CLK_M4_SCU_CFG_bit.RUN = 1;

  /* Set I2C0 module frequency = APB1 freq */
  I2C0_PCLK = 160000000;
}

/*************************************************************************
 * Function Name: RIT_IRQHandler
 * Parameters: none
 *
 * Return: none
 *
 * Description: Repetitive interrupt timer handler
 *
 *************************************************************************/
void RITIMER_IRQHandler(void)
{
    flTickSet();
    /* Clear interrupt */
    RIT_CTRL_bit.RITINT = 1;
    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(NVIC_RITIMER);
}

/*************************************************************************
 * Function Name: RIT_Init
 * Parameters: none
 *
 * Return: none
 *
 * Description: Initialization of repetitive interrupt timer
 *
 *************************************************************************/
void RITIMER_Init(void)
{
  /* Value for 0.25s timer interrupt @ 180MHz timer clock */
  RIT_COUNTER = 0;
  RIT_COMPVAL = 0x2AEA540;
  RIT_CTRL_bit.RITEN = 1;
  RIT_CTRL_bit.RITENCLR = 1;
  /* Enable interrupt */
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(NVIC_RITIMER);
  NVIC_SetPriority(NVIC_RITIMER, 16);
}

/*************************************************************************
 * Function Name: main
 * Parameters: none
 *
 * Return: none
 *
 * Description: main
 *
 *************************************************************************/
int main()
{
  // Configures Clock Generation Unit
  InitClock();
  // Force a RESET to Cortex-M0
  RGU_RESET_CTRL1 = ~RGU_RESET_ACTIVE_STATUS1 | RGU_RESET_CTRL1_M0APP_RST;
  // Configures Repetitve Interrupt Timer
  RITIMER_Init();
  // Configure the onboard LED - GPIO4.1
  GPIO_CLR4 = 1 << 1;
  GPIO_DIR4 |= 1 << 1;
  // Init I2C
  I2C_InitMaster(400000);

  // Everything below this line I have added in myself - Mitchell

  /* Configure PC_11 and PC_12 to serve as
     GPIO6[10] and GPIO6[11] to act as data select
     for SPP0_SSEL multiplexer

     1. Set as outputs
     2. Choose INTLCD_SSEL (option 0) as output by clearing both outputs
     3. Configure both pins as GPIO
  */

  // 1
  GPIO_DIR6 |= 0x0C;

  // 2
  GPIO_PIN6 &= ~0x0C;;

  // 3
  SCU_SFSPC_11_bit.MODE = 4;
  SCU_SFSPC_12_bit.MODE = 4;

  // Set LCD_RST to reset the LCD
  RGU_RESET_CTRL0 |= RGU_RESET_CTRL0_LCD_RST;
  // LCD_RST autoclears when complete
  // wait until this done before moving on
  while(RGU_RESET_STATUS1_bit.LCD_RST == 1);

  /* SPI slave select is an active low signal.
     This means that to communicate with the onboard LCD,
     SSP0_SSEL must be cleared
  */


  while(1)
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: The `B.N` instruction is simply an (unconditional) branch instruction. The `.N` suffix tells the assembler to encode the instruction using 16 bits. At address 0x40 you're branching to address 0x40, i.e. you've created an infinite loop. Is this handwritten Thumb assembly or was it generated by a compiler? What is it supposed to do? (the code makes very little sense).

Comment: Strange; there shouldn't be any infinite loops in my program.

I wrote the software in C, the assembler was generated using the IAR C/C++ compiler. Is the code nonsense because it lacks context? (ie would it help if I explained what the program is supposed to do)

Comment: It looks like bogus code to me. What does the memory map of the NXP LPC1850 look like? (i.e. is there supposed to be any code at address 0?). My first guess would be that you've got a bug somewhere in your program that causes it to incorrectly branch to address 0, or somewhere thereabout, where it starts executing garbage.

Comment: Memory map says addresses 0x00000000 to 0x10000000 belong to a "256 MB shadow area".

I built my code on top of an example provided with the IDE. I've commented out the six lines of code I added, cleaned the project and rebuilt it. Still having the same problem. 

Would it be helpful to share my C code?

Comment: That might help. I'd also suggest stepping through the code or using breakpoints to try to find out from where it came before ending up at address 0.

Comment: I've tried stepping and breakpointing. No success. The only thing that happens is when I halt, the cursor is at memory address 0x40.

I added the C listing to my original post.

Answer (score 6):

In Cortex-M3, the lowest addresses are not code, but [the vector table](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABIFJFG.html). For example, entry at 0 is the reset value of `SP`, at 4 is the reset `PC`, and the following entries are various exceptions. If we reinterptet the dump as data, we get the following:

```
00 DCD 0x10089FF0
04 DCD 0x10402BAD
08 DCD 0x10400041
0C DCD 0x10400043
10 DCD 0x10400045
14 DCD 0x10400047
18 DCD 0x10400049
1C DCD 0
20 DCD 0
24 DCD 0
28 DCD 0
2C DCD 0x1040004B
30 DCD 0x1040004D
34 DCD 0
38 DCD 0x1040004F
3C DCD 0x10401645
```

It becomes obvious that the code has been linked to run from 10400000. If we take that into account, and convert integers to offsets, we get:

```
00  DCD 0x10089FF0          ; Initial SP
04  DCD 0x10402BAD          ; reset PC
08  DCD loc_10400040+1      ; NMI handler
0C  DCD loc_10400042+1      ; Hard Fault handler
10  DCD loc_10400044+1      ; MPU Fault Handler
14  DCD loc_10400046+1      ; Bus Fault Handler
18  DCD loc_10400048+1      ; Usage Fault Handler
1C  DCD 0
20  DCD 0
24  DCD 0
28  DCD 0
2C  DCD loc_1040004A+1      ; SVCall Handler
30  DCD loc_1040004C+1      ; Debug Monitor Handler
34  DCD 0
38  DCD loc_1040004E+1      ; PendSV Handler
3C  DCD 0x10401645          ; SysTick Handler

40 loc_10400040
40   B loc_10400040
```

(The offsets have +1 because the code pointers on Cortex-M3 must have bit 0 set, to indicate that the target is Thumb code.)

The `loc_10400040` corresponds to the `B.N 0x40` in your disassembly. So, apparently, you ended up in the NMI handler.

Checking the LPC18xx User Manual, it seems NMI can only be triggered by the pins `P4_0` or `PE_4`. I'd suggest double-checking your board schematics and/or GPIO configuration code.

Comment: Neither P4_0 or PE_4 are not configured -- every pin is hooked up to a MUX, so unless they are specifically configured to act as NMI pin, a signal applied to the NMI pin should go nowhere.

Comment: Also possible is that something jumped or returned execution to address zero and the vector table executed as code, ending up at address 0x40 and looping there. It looks as though all the vectors end up being valid assembly (or at least the disassembler was able to figure it out).

Answer (score 0):

- First, you should check to make sure that all optimizations are off (look in project options). If you're curious what the optimizations are doing, introduce them one at a time after turning them off, and observe how the assembly changes.
- Those MOVS instructions seem to be acting as NOPs that essentially provide execution delay. These may be replacing one or more while loops as a result of compiler optimization.

  - Inline delay instructions are more optimal, and sometimes replace circular conditional branching (while loops) if the compiler determines that the delay can be pre-determined.
- The B.N instructions, as mentioned in the comments, are providing the infinite loop. You DO in-fact have AT LEAST one infinite loop in your code, at the end of main.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same type of issue during i was writing uart library using assembly and c. the problem in my code was i enabling a bit which had to be enabled only after few configuration. like enabling PLLON before configuring pll register gave me the issue